# loop:true; OWL CAROUSEL

Tags: jquery, carousel

Owl Corousel not looping to infinity here is my code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    loop:true,
    autoPlay: 7000,
    items : 4,
    itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3],
  });

});
</script>
```

Does anyone know why the loop doesn't work? Everything works fine except looping to infinity.

How i want it to loop:
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

Thanks in advance, i am a beginner at jquery.

Comment: According to the docs you dont need anything else, however it does say infinity loop is a new feature, are you using an up to date version?

Comment: according to CHANGELOG.HTML i am using 1.3.3 Oh i think i have to use beta for this feature! thanks, let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used version 1.3.3., In order to use the feature you have to use beta version which you can access here:¨http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

Regards!